# Cropping a PDF File's Margin During Printing

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I'm using the free Acrobat Reader to print out some pdf documents having very large top/bottom/left/right margins.  I want to remove the margins (which are wasting too much space and making the fonts too small).  I used to use Acrobat (the paid version having edit features) to crop the src pdf file manually.  But since it is an old version it does not support new pdf format and I don't want to upgrade for such a simple use.

Is there any free way to crop/remove unwanted white margins from the printed pdf?

I am thinking to print the pdf files to a PDF Printer like the Bullzip PDF Printer and enlarge the output file manually so as to remove any white margin.  But there does not seem to be such a feature in Bullzip PDF Printer.  Is there any other virtual printer software that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Foxit PDF editor (not the reader) can do it, you install it, open your PDF, choose document --> layout --> right click the page you want to crop and choose "clip content".

Supposedly the drawback to the free evaluation version is it adds some sort of watermark... but I can't see it. Maybe it got removed when I cropped the page. Or maybe page cropping is not a big enough change for the watermark to be added.

Comment: The problem with Foxit and similar tools is that your changes look nice when you see them on screen, but when you print the page appears with the old margins and scale again.
An older tool than sometimes works is "Advanced PDF Tools" (option page conten scaling)

Comment: In the new version it's a little different:
Choose Organize > Crop Pages.
From the right click context menu on the Pages thumbnails, choose Crop Pages.
In the Crop Pages dialog box, adjust values for the Margin Controls: Top, Bottom, Left, and Right. A black rectangle in the thumbnail page display shows the adjusted boundaries of the cropped page.
Under Page Range:
To crop all pages in the PDF, select All.
To crop only one page or a range of pages, select From, and enter page numbers in the From and To options.
Click OK.

Comment: And it didn't work for me unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Here i want to recommend you one is not a printer but has the print function,too.

Basically is [**a PDF editor**](http://www.convertpdf.org/edit-pdf-file.html) that you can use the cropping tool in it to conver the valuable content, then the margin out of it will be removed and thus the fonts will be enlarged.I think it is what you want to get.

But just like other desktop one its trail verision will leave a watermark! Good luck to you!